# Numpy: how to map an element to an array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 2D `numpy` array, say `5*3`. Now I would like to map each element `i` in it to a new array `[i, i*i]`, so the resulting array is `5*3*2`.

What is the most efficient (and elegant) way to achieve this purpose?

A naive solution using `for`:

```
a = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)
r = []
for row in a:
   _row = []
   for i in row:
      _row.append([i, i*i])
   r.append(_row)
return np.array(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`np.dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to stack both arrays depth wise:

```
np.dstack([a, a**2])
```

---

```
a = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)

array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])

np.dstack([a, a**2])

array([[[  0,   0],
        [  1,   1],
        [  2,   4]],

       [[  3,   9],
        [  4,  16],
        [  5,  25]],
 ...
```

Comment: what if the desired `map` is a complicated function? For example, `def func(i)` returns `[x, y]`, while this `func` is not trival like `[i, i**2]`.

Comment: I think it would be more appropiate to ask this in a new question @chenzhongpu , note that this was not included in the question, and the corresponding answer would be quite different. Feel free to ping me here when you do so!